# Where are virtualenvwrapper functions sourced in Linux when installed by apt-get?

Tags: bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I was following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login

And couldn't find any mention of `mkvirtualenv` and friends in any of my login files. But `type mkvirtualenv` reveals

```
mkvirtualenv is a function
mkvirtualenv ()
{
...
```

So it's clearly being defined somewhere. I found no mention in .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/*, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/bash.bashrc.d.

I'm using bash version 4.4.12 and virtualenv version 15.1.0.

Comment: Start a shell with `bash -x` or `bash -lx` (for a login shell) and look for `.`/`source` commands to see which file might be defining `mkvirtualenv`.

Comment: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html, though, suggests you are looking for `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`, which should be getting sourced from one of the standard configuration files (most likely `.bashrc`).